# statistics on subsets of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider this pandas dataframe:

```
            A  B  C  D
2012-08-16  2  1  1  7
2012-08-17  6  4  8  6
2012-08-18  8  3  1  1
2012-08-19  7  2  8  9
2012-08-20  6  7  5  8
2012-08-21  1  3  3  3
2012-08-22  8  2  3  8
2012-08-23  7  1  7  4
2012-08-24  2  6  0  6
2012-08-25  4  6  8  1
```

I would like to make statistics by making subsets on values contained in the column A. A minimal example to achieve that is:

```
new = pd.DataFrame()
for id in set(df.A):
    sub = df[df.A == id)
    new = new.append([{'B_mean': sub.B.mean(), 'B_std': sub.B.std(), 'id': id},])
```

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do that.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) on `groupby`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?  It calculated the mean and standard deviation on each ID grouping from A.

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': ['mean', 'std']})
      B          
   mean       std
A                
1   3.0       NaN
2   3.5  3.535534
4   6.0       NaN
6   5.5  2.121320
7   1.5  0.707107
8   2.5  0.707107
```